# crontab grep function execution

Tags: cron

When I  tried exection grep function in particular directory its working on that directory but when I am trying to execute using absolute paths grep is not working for example

```
 grep `date +%Y-%m-%d` /var/wwww/file/file.log >> /home/filename/file.log
```

The above command  output getting as empty file.
Is it possible to schedule  grep in crontab to match text and generate valid output ?

Comment: the question you linked, does not as far as I can see handle the % problem ... it is just a rather generic explanation

Comment: you may want to edit the title of this question, to reflect the problem you ran into :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `%` in your crontab file gets turned into a newline character unless escaped with a backslash. Try

```
grep `date +\%Y-\%m-\%d` /var/wwww/file/file.log >> /home/filename/file.log
```

see

```
man 5 crontab
```

for details.

Comment: its working great from command line but how to set this as cronjob ? do you think grep works inside cron ?

Comment: its working as crob job too !!!!

Comment: the `%` in the crontab problem happens to me every few years as I tend to forget this special handling :)

Comment: It saved my day. I just want to write a bash script for automation for present day log. I am very noob in bash script so instead of going for bash script i thought about grep and cron. They just worked for me prefectly.